# Take picture when phone is straight

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensormanager

I just want to ask a question because I've searched through Google and I can't seem to find anything useful, and read about [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html).

The Question is, can I take a picture from camera only when the phone is straight using sensors in android device?

Just looking for advice on how to do it?

Comment: Please explain, completely and precisely, what "straight" means. For example, if I am standing on the deck of a ship, "straight" could be relative to the deck of the ship, or it could be relative to the water's surface, or it could be relative to the horizon, or it could be relative to the particular item that I am viewing from the camera in a preview.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I mean when i hold the phone in straight line http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/42300/42322/stline_42322_lg.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the orientation sensor and SensorEvents.

> The orientation sensor lets you monitor the position of a device relative >to the earth's frame of reference (specifically, magnetic north).
>
> The orientation sensor derives its data by using a device's geomagnetic >field sensor in combination with a device's accelerometer. Using these two >hardware sensors, an orientation sensor provides data for the following >three dimensions:
>
> > Azimuth (degrees of rotation around the z axis). This is the angle between magnetic north and the device's y axis. For example, if the device's y axis is aligned with magnetic north this value is 0, and if the device's y axis is pointing south this value is 180. Likewise, when the y axis is pointing east this value is 90 and when it is pointing west this value is 270.
> >
> > Pitch (degrees of rotation around the x axis). This value is positive when the positive z axis rotates toward the positive y axis, and it is negative when the positive z axis rotates toward the negative y axis. The range of values is 180 degrees to -180 degrees.
> >
> > Roll (degrees of rotation around the y axis). This value is positive when the positive z axis rotates toward the positive x axis, and it is negative when the positive z axis rotates toward the negative x axis. The range of values is 90 degrees to -90 degrees.

Using these values you should be able to tell when the phone is "straight" in any position.  There are examples on the page under the "Using the orientation sensor" header :  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-orient

Also look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html which shows how to use the sensor events

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, where you are capturing image use

int i =  getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

through this, you will get current orientation of mobile, if it is portrait then only capture the image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i want the phone itself to be straight.